# Error: Unknown argument --licenses flutter doctor --android-licenses

Tags: android, linux, bash, flutter, sdk

I tried to install the android SDK with vscode to write flutter. But whenever a start android emulator it asked for licenses. But whenever I use command flutter doctor android licenses. It gives me this error. I am using,
**ANDROID SDK PLATFORM TOOLS - 29.0.6

ANDROID SDK BUILD TOOLS - 29.0.3

ANDROID 7 (API:24)**

```
flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.1, on Linux, locale en_US.utf8)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
    ✗ Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#android-setup for more details.
[!] Android Studio (not installed)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.50.0)
[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 3 categories.
```

I tried many StackOverflow solutions but it didn't work out. maybe outdated.

```
 flutter doctor --android-licenses
Error: Unknown argument --licenses
Usage: 
  sdkmanager [--uninstall] [<common args>] \
    [--package_file <package-file>] [<packages>...]
  sdkmanager --update [<common args>]
  sdkmanager --list [<common args>]

In its first form, installs, or uninstalls, or updates packages.
    <package> is a sdk-style path (e.g. "build-tools;23.0.0" or 
             "platforms;android-23").
    <package-file> is a text file where each line is a sdk-style path
                   of a package to install or uninstall.
    Multiple --package_file arguments may be specified in combination
     with explicit paths.
In its second form (with --update), currently installed packages are
    updated to the latest version.
In its third form, all installed and available packages are printed out.

Common Arguments:
    --sdk_root=<sdkRootPath>: Use the specified SDK root instead of the SDK containing this tool
    --channel=<channelId>: Include packages in channels up to <channelId>.
                           Common channels are:
                           0 (Stable), 1 (Beta), 2 (Dev), and 3 (Canary).

    --include_obsolete: With --list, show obsolete packages in the
                        package listing. With --update, update obsolete                                                                                                                                          
                        packages as well as non-obsolete.                                                                                                                                                        
    --no_https: Force all connections to use http rather than https.                                                                                                                                             
    --proxy=<http | socks>: Connect via a proxy of the given type.                                                                                                                                               
    --proxy_host=<IP or DNS address>: IP or DNS address of the proxy to use.                                                                                                                                     
    --proxy_port=<port #>: Proxy port to connect to.                                                                                                                                                             
                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
* If the env var REPO_OS_OVERRIDE is set to "windows",                                                                                                                                                           
  "macosx", or "linux", packages will be downloaded for that OS.
```

So how can I activate the license for android SDK?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue when I ran `flutter doctor --android-licenses`. And I had android SDK installed without using Android Studio.

Here are the steps I took to make it work

1. I went to [android studio download page](https://developer.android.com/studio#downloads) and scrolled down and downloaded the command line tools for my OS (windows)
2. Then I extracted it to the `android-sdk` directory
3. I created a new folder called `latest` inside `cmdline-tools` and moved the content of `cmdline-tools` to it.

After this I tried to run  `flutter doctor --android-licenses` and then it worked without errors and ran it on my device no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Install Android SDK 6.0(Marshmallow)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by installing android studio and uninstall all android files and reinstall from android studio. Then automatically the license created in the folder. now whenever I run the emulator from vscode.. it is working smoothly.

I faced the problem because I installed all android files from android sdk directly. I installed android sdk by sudo snap android-sdk. so it created the problem for me.
To know more in detailed you can read this article - [Flutter, Android SDK and VScode setup on Linux Complete Guideline](https://technologea.com/flutter-android-sdk-and-vscode-setup-on-linux/)

Answer (score 0):

This issue would occur if you do not have the command-line tools in your `<sdk>/cmdline-tools\latest` directory. Instead of installing Android Studio, you can download command line tools from [here](https://developer.android.com/studio#downloads) and put it in the directory  `<sdk>/cmdline-tools\latest`